# Error in reading shp file in Rstudio with different libraries

Tags: r, rstudio

I am having issue reading shape file in R. I tried using both `rgdal` with `readOGR` command and `sf` with `read_sf` command. But I get the error in the attached figure. The strange thing is that sometimes it manages to read the same file without problems. I have the same issue with all shp files, also coming from different sources.

I run Linux with a AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon Graphics CPU.
I tried disable the use GPU exclusion list and the following line in the global option.
I upgraded recently the version of RStudio. I currently have R version 4.3.3 and Rstudio 2023.06.1+524

[image]

Comment: How large is the file? How much RAM do you have on that system? Is this a linux system?

Comment: Are you sure the shp file isn't corrupted? Are you able to read it using `ogrinfo` or QGIS?

Comment: Yes, it is Linux. I have 16 GB of RAM. The file is few MB. I can read it with both ogrinfo and QGIS.

Comment: There were similar issue(s) reported: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7310. As a possible(?) solution there is a suggestion to change the rendering engine https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/360017886674-Troubleshooting-RStudio-Rendering-Errors.